# How to use SELECT + parameter + FROM in SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I want to know if it is possible to create a query like that:

```
SELECT :parameterA, :paramaterB 
FROM *someTable*;
```

The idea is to use some structure like that instead of making some sort of string or something like that.

I´m working with SQL database and a C# project in Visual Studio 2019.

So far I have this code:

```
    public List<V_Requerimientos> GetData(int idEmpresa, string columns)
    {
        List<V_Requerimientos> result = null;

        try
        {
            var dyParam = new OracleDynamicParameters();
            dyParam.Add("idEmpresa", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input, value: idEmpresa);

            var conn = this.GetConnection();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string query = "SELECT " + columns + "FROM V_REQUERIMIENTOS " +                      
                    "WHERE EMPR_CODIGO = :idEmpresa AND ETAR_CODIGO <> 4";
                result= conn.Query<V_Requerimientos>(query, dyParam).ToList();

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        return result;
}
```

where `idEmpresa` is the PK of the object selected in the front, and columns is a string which contains the columns I want to select for that object.

I was wondering if there is anyway for replace columns for parameters sent to the method instead of using the concatenated query as I have at the moment.

Comment: _I'm working with SQL database..._ Exactly which SQL database platform is that?

Comment: Yes, this can be accomplished a few ways. Can you please update your post to include what you have done and what isn't working so we can help you?

Comment: You can't specify columns as parameters. A SQL query is essentially a program compiled by the server into an execution plan. The tables and columns are the types. If they change, you need to compile a new program. It's not a naming issue. The same query will result in a different execution plan (ie compiled program) if it's covered by an index, if it has too few unique values, if a CHECK constraint tells the server what values to expect etc. Parameters are only used to pass *values* to a query, the same way function parameters do

Comment: If you want to change the columns at runtime you need to create the SQL query dynamically, or use an ORM to do this

Answer (score 0):

SQL parameters are used to specify value in the where clause. You would not use parameters for column names. Your query should look more like this.

```
string colA = "Customer Id";
string colB = "Customer Name";
string sql = $"Select [{colA}], [{colB}] from table";
```